# StageVideo fallback in Air mobile doesn't work. Video component won't play .mp4

Tags: android, ios, video, actionscript, air

So with StageVideo you can play a h264 .mp4 file, and by any example which I found you need to have a fallback Video component.

1. Problem is that I was unable to play the .mp4 video files with the Video component on a mobile device, Android or iOS.
   .flv works fine, but I can't have backup video files as it takes too much space.
2. Is it really necessary to have the fallback to the Video component? what are the chances it will fail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experiences (I've created 3 separate AIR VOD apps for both iOS and Android), the following is true:

1. `StageVideo` works on Android 4.0+. I was unable to get it to work with 3.x, but I have been told it works. I can, for sure, confirm that it does not work on 2.x.
2. `StageVideo` works on iOS 5+. On iOS 5, you will need to play a silent sound at startup to make sure sound works, but you should do that regardless since the iPad 2 rarely plays sound without doing that. It is a known bug in AIR that, as far as I know, has never been attempted to be fixed
3. iOS **can only** play h.264 MP4s through `StageVideo` and `StageWebView`. They will not work in Flash video players (including `VideoDisplay`, the base for `Video` and all OSMF-based players). I do not recall the exact reason for this, but I believe it has something to do with the MP4 requirement for hardware accelerated playback.
4. iOS can play FLV and, maybe, F4V through the Flash video players described in #3. This will lack hardware acceleration, however. That means your video and your UI will run on the same thread and share the same process. Basically, lower framerates while video is playing. Additionally, CPU decoding is a battery drain.
5. Android is a little more wild. You *cannot* use `StageWebView` for any playback as of Android 4.3 (have not tested on 4.4 yet). You *can* use Flash video players for h.264 MP4s... on some devices. I've found that they seem to work fine on Android 3.0+ on all devices I have tested. Keep in mind that is only a couple dozen out of over a thousand possibilities, though. On 2.x, it is extremely hit-or-miss. It seems to work fine on HTC and Motorola devices (which I've tested on), but I have had reports from users who cannot playback on Samsung and Sony devices.

As you mentioned, a fallback player **is definitely recommended**. Without having multiple sources/encode types, the fallback is useless on iOS, however. I currently have an app in the Play Store (All About Trikes) that was originally released without a fallback player and just used a `StageVideo` implementation. A day after release, we started getting reports that users on 2.x couldn't play videos. We had to scramble. We first released a version that couldn't be installed on 2.x and then another version that uses Flex's `VideoDisplay` as a fallback, which seems to have fixed the problem for those users, but I know there will be others than cannot playback video.

Long story short, there is no fool-proof way of playing back h.264 MP4s on mobile using AIR. You **do** want to include a fallback player, regardless of platform. Ideally, if you are streaming the video, you should have both h.264 MP4s and FLVs available with the fallback using FLVs instead of MP4s.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer!
I'm gonna use StageVideo only for iOS. I do not stream and do not have the option to supply a backup flv's.
I guess I'm going to have to use only StageVideo with not fallback and hope for the best.
With Android I will use only Video since the StageVideo has a bug there for short clips (doesn't play them all the way through).

Comment: @mik Don't forget to play a silent mp3 at launch using `Sound` to ensure all platforms can play sound. I generally use http://www.xamuel.com/blank-mp3s/

Comment: Thanks, but I play short clips with no sound, but I will remember this for future use!
So I actually need to limit my app for iOS 5.0 and above in the descriptor file if I'm using StageVideo, right?

Comment: I'm unsure. I've had it successfully work on iOS 5+ but I don't believe I've ever tested on iOS 4 or below. Restricting it to 5+ really isn't that bad, though, since less than 3% of iOS users are on 5 now and less than 1% are on <4. Those users are nearly 3 years behind. We can't continue supporting old software indefinitely, you know?

Comment: Yeah.. so I don't think it's too risky for me not to put an iOS limitation. great ;)